# How to downgrade OpenCV 3.2 to 3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: opencv

I installed OpenCV 3.2 + Python 2.7 following this tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

Now I want to downgrade it to 3.1, how can I do this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: im shocked this has no answer considering how much of a pain it is to make opencv work with anything.

Answer (score 1):

go to the build folder in your opencv folder. There should be a cmake_uninstall file. If so, just write

`sudo make uninstall`

and the installation gets removed. Use then

http://www.pytorials.com/how-to-install-opencv340-on-ubuntu1604/

to reinstall openCV properly again.